# Converting VB.NET code to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have the follwing VB.NET code I am trying to convert to C#.

```
Dim decryptedBytes(CInt(encryptedStream.Length - 1)) As Byte
```

I tried this:

```
int tempData = Convert.ToInt32(encryptedStream.Length - 1);
Byte decryptedBytes;
decryptedBytes = decryptedBytes[tempData];
```

But got this error message:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type byte.

Please note that the VB.NET code works.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [SharpDevelop code converter](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx), the output for your VB code is:

```
byte[] decryptedBytes = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(encryptedStream.Length - 1) + 1];
```

Note that VB specifies for upper bound of the array where C# specifies the length, so the converter added the "+ 1".

I would simplify that to:

```
byte[] decryptedBytes = new byte[(int)encryptedStream.Length];
```

Comment: You can probably remove the `(int)` cast, too.  I'll be very surprised if the Length property here isn't already an int.

Comment: Documentation disagrees with you: `public int Length { get; }` and `Type: System.Int32` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: @R. Bemrose: System.IO.Stream, not String.

Answer (score 1):

byte[] decryptedBytes = new byte[(Int32)encryptedStream.Length];

By the way if you have further problems try this:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: DeveloperFusion is using an old version of the SharpDevelop code converter (NRefactory). Better use http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx.
For example, the cast to int would have subtly different behavior than the original VB code if the Length property returned a double - this is why never versions of the converter use Convert.ToInt32().

Comment: +1 That is the link I was going to provide. There's another: c# to VB at http://www.developerfusion.com/tools